# How to merge column data using the last updated value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Somewhat confusing so its easier if I put down example and expected output to begin.

I have a table that could look like this: (Unit1 - Unit2 columns could span up to 30 columns in the same general format)

```
| ID | Name | Unit1_left | Unit2_left |
| 1  | Tom  |     50     |     NULL   |
| 2  | Tom  |    NULL    |      1     |
| 3  | Tom  |     45     |     NULL   |
| 4  | Dan  |    NULL    |     NULL   |
```

What I am trying to select is a table like this:

```
| Name | Unit1_left | Unit2_left |
| Tom  |     45     |      1     |
| Dan  |    NULL    |     NULL   |
```

What that is doing is grouping by name and attempting to find the last values in the 2 other columns if they exist (if not then it returns NULL).

I have looked at various other questions and they all say to use `Max()` however this will not work since it selects the highest value (incorrect). I have seen that in MsSQL there is a `Last()` function which looks vaguely like what I want it to do but its not implemented in MySQL and isn't exactly what I need anyway.

What I am trying to ask is, does anyone know of a possible method of selecting the data like this or if I will have to use a separate programming language to do this?

Comment: What criteria are you using to judge the 'last values in the 2 other columns'?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean but basically lets say the table is sorted by ID ascending where `Name`=Tom. I cant easily explain it but lets say you went through the column `Unit1_Left` in reverse (45, NULL, 50) when you hit a number thats the number I want it to select. Same with `Unit2_left`. Hope that explains it a little better than what I put in the first post.

Comment: In other words, why did you choose Tom's `45` value rather than the `50`? Is it because the value in column ID is higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the result set you've described

```
SELECT dname.name, 
       l1value.unit1_left, 
       l2value.unit2_left 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT `name` 
        FROM   table1) `DName` 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `name`, 
                         Max(id) id 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  unit1_left IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP  BY `name`) l1 
              ON dname.`name` = l1.`name` 
       LEFT JOIN table1 l1value 
              ON l1.id = l1value.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `name`, 
                         Max(id) id 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  unit2_left IS NOT NULL 
                  GROUP  BY `name`) l2 
              ON dname.`name` = l2.`name` 
       LEFT JOIN table1 l2value 
              ON l2.id = l2value.id ;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89123/24)

I did it by creating 2 inline views to the highest id for non-null values for both unit1_left and unit2_left (l1 and l2). Then joined it back to original table to get the values (l1value and l2value). We then join that back to a third inline view (dname) that creates the distinct names.

It's quite messy and it might make more sense just to keep your data in a more sensible manner.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was after... The reason the data isn't kept in a sensible manner is because I don't have control over that side of things. The data is pulled directly from a site and then parsed into a local database which I can only select from. I was trying to find a way of making the data more easily used which is the reasoning for needing this code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries in you select statement. Using SqlFidlle I came up with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e65/11).

```
select o.name,
      (select o2.Unit1_left 
         from original as o2
         where o.name = o2.name
             and o2.Unit1_left is not null
         order by o2.id desc
         LIMIT 1) as Unit1_left,
      (select o3.Unit2_left 
         from original as o3
         where o.name = o3.name
             and o3.Unit2_left is not null
         order by o3.id desc
         LIMIT 1) as Unit2_left
    from original as o 
       group by o.name
       order by id;
```